# how to pass an element to a nested stack in spine.js

Tags: javascript, spine.js

i have a Controller which holds a `Spine.Model` instance and has a nested `Spine.Stack`,
how can i pass the model instance to the nested stacks Controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out.
every Controller in a stack has the stack at `@stack` so passing objects to a stack makes those available also on the Controllers

Comment: But `@stack` property isn't created automatically, is it? The stack is passed into the controller constructor (when creating by the stack) but it seems the controller have to set the property manually.

Comment: no the controller gets the stack property set automatically. you can access it by accessing `@stack`.

Comment: Can you please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11470680/388834 ? When `@stack = parameters.stack` line removed from the controller constructor it doesn't work (I cannot access via `@stack`). Something wrong with that?

Comment: check here https://github.com/maccman/spine/blob/master/src/manager.coffee#L67 every controller added gets the stack passed in. access `@stack` in every function in the controller without setting it explicitly. not sure why you cant. my contstructor simply looks like this:   `constructor: ->` and i call super right after. not sure if it depends because you call super after setting the variables.

Comment: actually im pretty sure that you will be able to access `@stack` if you after the `super`.

Comment: +1 Thank you very much! Yes, it's set automatically by `super` call. The point is that it could be used *after* the base constructor called. But in my case (linked answer) I need to have `@el` set *before* base constructor called -- because events delegation is set in the base constructor so `@el` have to be already set at the moment of `super` calling. So for that reason I have to set `@stack` manually. But in general it is done automatically.