# 'active' class not added when Spine.js controller stack used

Tags: coffeescript, spine.js

I have two very simple Spine.js controllers:

```
class ListController extends Spine.Controller
    className: 'list'
    constructor: () ->
        super

class DetailController extends Spine.Controller
    className: 'detail'
    constructor: () ->
        super
```

controller stack

```
class Application extends Spine.Stack
    className: 'mystack'
    controllers:
         list: ListController
         detail: DetailController
```

and corresponding HTML markup

```
<div class="mystack">
    <div class="list">list</div>
    <div class="detail">detail</div>
</div>
```

My problem is that when controller stack instantiated

```
app = new Application()
app.list.active()
```

there is no `active` class added to the `div.list` element. Divs remain unchanged.

What is wrong with that?

Comment: maybe leave out the className attributes. also do you test that active() is working via the console? have you tested that the very most basic setup works? http://spinejs.com/docs/stacks

Comment: You are right, `className` is irrelevant in this case. Thank you. I've just found the solution so I'll post it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just got it so I'll describe basic working example. There are several issues with the code above (caused by my misunderstanding of how Spine.js controller stack works :-)

First, appropriate HTML element have to be associated with every controller managed by the stack. When controller stack instantiates the controller it passes only `stack` (i.e. itself) instance as parameter to the constructor. So controller constructor have to take it into account (e.g. like the following):

```
class ListController extends Spine.Controller
    constructor: (parameters) ->
        @stack = parameters.stack
        @el = $ @stack.settings.listSelector
        super

class DetailController extends Spine.Controller
    constructor: (parameters) ->
        @stack = parameters.stack
        @el = $ @stack.settings.detailSelector
        super
```

and the stack:

```
class Application extends Spine.Stack
    settings:
        listSelector: '.list'
        detailSelector: '.detail'
    controllers:
        list: ListController
        detail: DetailController
    default:
        'list'
```

then the controller stack could be instantiated:

```
app = new Application
    el: $ '.mystack'
```

`ListController` will be active (i.e. corresponding `div` has `active` class added) by default and anytime later you can call `@stack.detail.active()` or `@stack.list.active()` from controller instance method to activate required controller and 'hide' (i.e. remove `active` class) the other(s).

**EDIT:**
We discussed the issue with @aschmid00. In fact, controller constructor doesn't have to set its own property `@stack` manually. It is done automatically when base constructor called by `super`. But in case of this question `@el` have to be set *before* base constructor called due to the events delegation etc.